# Returning value for function that throws

Tags: swift

I've got a pretty simple question but I could only find a similar answer in C++ thread. Compiler complains on `getUserFromServer` function stating that it requires `return` value even though it can catch an exception. It is obvious WHY it asks for return value but I'm not sure how to handle the situation properly.

One way is to create some sort of dummy `user` and return it but it doesn't sound any good. Another way is by making return type `Optional` but it's just moving responsibility for nil-checks to another level, which is probably not a good idea. Any help would help.

Here's a setup to simulate behaviour I expect in real code.

```
enum TestError: Error {
    case JustError
}

class User {}
class ServerClient {
    func getUser(really: Bool) throws -> User {
        var uza: User?
        if really {
            uza = User()
        }
        guard let user = uza else {
            throw TestError.JustError
        }
        return user
    }
}

func getUserFromServer() -> User {

    let client = ServerClient()
    let user: User

    do {
        user = try client.getUser(really: true)
        return user
    } catch TestError.JustError {
        print("just an error occured")
    } catch {
        print("something terrible happened")
    }
} //Error: missing return in a function
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So imagine I'm a the caller, and I write this line of code:

```
let user = getUserFromServer()
print(user)
```

It fails somehow. Great. What do you want to happen? What should `user` be? What should print? (There's no right answer here; the question really is what do *you* want it to be?)

If you want `user` to be nil, then `getUserFromServer` should return `User?`. If you want `user` to be some default user, then you'll need a way to create that. If you want the caller to not print at all (and instead handle some error), then `getUserFromServer()` should throw. If you want it to crash, then you need to add a `fatalError` inside `getUserFromServer`. These are all valid, but it has to do *something*, and what that something is, is up to you.

That said, if the question is just advice about what it should be, looking at this code you should probably default to making it an optional unless you need some other behavior. That would be the "normal" thing here since you already "handled" the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed.